# Finding the subgroups of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a question on my math homework that asks me to find 3 subgroups of Z(mod10) = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}.

I understand that the subgroups must hold under the associative, identity, inverse, and closure axioms, but I don't understand the axioms and how to show that a subgroup holds under these axioms. I know that the answer will be {0}, {0, 5}, and {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}, but I do not know how to prove this. I would like to have a method that I can use for all Z mod X.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{10}$ under addition is [cyclic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups#:~:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20every%20subgroup,fundamental%20theorem%20of%20cyclic%20groups.). Are you looking only for proper subgroups?

Comment: For a well known lemma, it suffices to find the closed subsets of the group.

Answer (score 0):

For any group $G$ you can generate a subgroup $H_g = \{g^n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Since $G=\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is finite and cyclic all of its subgroups can be generated this way including $G$. Calculate the value of $H_0$ through $H_9$ and you'll discover some of them generate the same group. Divisibility is important here so look for patterns in the generators to figure out which is which.